# Sharepoint event error 2436 - search function failing

Tags: sharepoint

PREFACE:  I'm not a Sharepoint admin...our Sharepoint admin left the company.

I am getting the following error every 5 minutes and can't figure out what the fix is:

> Event Type:   Warning Event
>   Source:   Windows SharePoint Services 3
>   Search Event Category:    Gatherer  Event
>   ID:   2436 Date:      7/27/2010
>   Time:     3:40:02 PM User:        N/A
>
> Computer: FWMSPAPL
>
> Description: The start address
>   sts3://fwmspapp:8270/contentdbid={083c7ae0-bc68-405e-a5e8-12eae72f1718}
>   cannot be crawled.
>
> Context: Application 'Search index
>   file on the search server', Catalog
>   'Search'
>
> Details:  The crawler could not
>   communicate with the server. Check
>   that the server is available and that
>   the firewall access is configured
>   correctly.   (0x80041200)

I know it is related to the Windows Sharepoint Search function that happens every 5 minutes.

This information may help:

FWMSPAPP = old Sharepoint application server.  Still on the network but doesn't do anything.

FWMSPAPL = current Sharepoint application server.  This is where the error is.

My thought is that it is trying to access the old application server during the search indexing crawl but can't figure out where this is set and why and what to do about it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about Sharepoint (yet- we're deploying an instance at one of my sites, but I digress), but I found some links that might help you.

http://www.jasonslater.co.uk/2008/08/06/moss-configuring-search/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101182/moss-2007-crawl

The second link has something similar to what you're experiencing, and the answers are kind of a mess, but they might help.